# Added UDID to IOS APP without WEB apple developer

Tags: xcode, service, iphone-developer-program

Developer Apple Service is closed. http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/

And how add udid and create new application without Developer Apple Service ?

Thanks for all
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to add any devices, create any profiles, add any users/certs, edit any provisioning profiles, create new App IDs, etc until Apple finishes the portal over haul.

While there is no workaround for the UDID issue a simple workaround for a new application would be to leverage an existing bundle identifier until things are back up and running. Keep in mind it will overwrite any app on those devices using that exact bundle identifier.